# what's wrong with this multiline url string?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying ES6 template literals for multiline strings. The following one works well:

```js
var customer = { name: "Foo" }
var card = { amount: 7, product: "Bar", unitprice: 42 }
var message = `Hello ${customer.name},
want to buy ${card.amount} ${card.product} for
a total of ${card.amount * card.unitprice} bucks?`
```

Then I tried to apply it to a URL string as follows:

```js
let topic = "pizza";
let url = `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&section=0&prop=text&format=json&page=${topic}`;
```

The single line version works well. But when I changed it to multiline, it didn't work:

```js
let topic = "pizza";
let url = `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php
?action=parse&section=0&prop=text&format=json&page=${topic}`;

or  
let url = `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php\
?action=parse&section=0&prop=text&format=json&page=${topic}`;
```

I used this URL to retrieve data:

```js
let https = require("https");
https.get(url, res => {...});
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the multiline URL? How can I do correctly? Thanks a lot.

Comment: **it didn't work** ... what didn't work? did you get an error? or is it the `.get` that fails? The issue *may* be, that by using template literals, the line break (\n or \r\n) will be part of the resulting string - that's not good for an URL

Comment: Well at least URL-encode it ... `encodeURIComponent` (Probably more a problem of neglecting that, than ES6 functionality to begin with.)

Comment: I don't think you want to `encodeURIComponent` on the `url` var itself - rather, just `${encodeURIComponent(topic)}`

Comment: Of course, anything else would not make sense.

Comment: Why not just removing that carriage return?

Comment: The first one will "work", while the browser takes care of encoding the characters requiring it in the query string. (`encodeURIComponent` should be used on parameter values where appropriate nevertheless.) The following version however always requests `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php\n` (line break at the end of path), no matter who takes care of encoding in the end. The first one did not mess up, because inside your message you _want_ line breaks - in your URL path however you don't, because that makes it a _different_ (and therefor wrong; betcha "didn't work" actually meant a 404) path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have newline characters in your url. Template literal syntax allow you to add newline characters to your string if you have newline chars in side of ``, so your URL has newline characters in it.

```
console.log('\n' === `
`) // true
```

Either do a String.prototype.replace() on the url before making the HTTP call

```
let topic = "pizza";
let url = `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php
?action=parse&section=0&prop=text&format=json&page=${topic}`;

// removes newline characters from template string
url.replace('\n', ''); 

// do your stuff here
let https = require("https");
https.get(url, res => {...});
```

Or escape the newline characters in the template string

```
let topic = "pizza";
// escape the newline character
let url = `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php\
?action=parse&section=0&prop=text&format=json&page=${topic}`;

// do your stuff here
let https = require("https");
https.get(url, res => {...});
```

Answer (score 0):

String literals retain the exact structure you write your lines in. So writing on a new line effectively adds a `\n` to your string.

```
let url = `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php\
?action=parse&section=0&prop=text&format=json&page=${topic}`;
```

As a string actually looks like this:

```
let url = `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php\\n?action=parse&section=0&prop=text&format=json&page=${topic}`;
```

That extra `\n` creates a an incorrect request to the server.

```js
let str = `I
am
a
string
literal`
console.log(str.split('\n'))
```

edit:
You can add an escape `\` to the end of each line to remove the `\n`. Thank you for the correction.

```js
let str = `I\
am\
a\
string\
literal`
console.log(str.split('\n'))
```

Comment: The second multi-line example from the question in which the newline is escaped with \ should be equivalent with writing it on a single line, shouldn't it?

Comment: The backslash at the end of the second multi-line example is indeed an escape character.

Comment: @tudorpavel Adjusted. Thank you

Comment: Don't mention it, but OP should explain why the second multi-line example still didn't work with `https.get(url)`.